# Fastest way to convert byte[] to string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arrays, unityscript

I need to convert a byte [] to string in C# and Unity without losing much of a Frame Per Second. I'm currently using the WWW class to fetch the text file, but when I use WWW.text, as the file is too large and causes a drop in FPS. Is there any way to make the conversion incrementally, without delay too long.

```
WWW file = new WWW(path);
yield return file;
string text= file.text;
```

I use this to read an full file(one .OBJ) and i need to read all text. Line to line or all text to one string to split after. To read text without drop in FPS, i make this.

```
WWW file = new WWW(path);
yield return file;
byte[] text= file.bytes;
```

if file are to much big, WWW.text, drop FPS, then i need use WWW.bytes. In Unity useyield return null; to process another frame. If process need too much time to execute then drop FPS(in case WWW.text);

Ex file: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/obj/cessna.obj

Comment: Well, how do you want to convert it? A string and a byte array are quite different beasts.

Comment: Is the file *actually* text, or is it binary data?

Comment: Is a text file, but is an online url.
Ex: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/obj/cessna.obj

Comment: That `yield` use is odd... Looks like an `await`.

Comment: In unity is evrithing single thread. Then you use `yield return null` to process another frame.
Another form is 

`WWW file = new WWW(path);
while (!file.isDone)
 {
     yield return null;
 }
byte[] text= file.bytes;`

Comment: You still have not told us what this is. Do you know? Do you even understand the question? How is the file encoded? UTF-8? ASCII? UTF-16? Some other way? These details are, well, critical.

Comment: You best shot i think is really loading the `byte[]` to `MemoryStream` and then writing to a string. You would save on the loading speed that's for sure but i doubt you would save on the overall time because of the conversion required to bring it to a string. Bu at least you can process the conversion on another thread object and the property return can yield until it actually finished the conversion. You would save some power but i don't think it would be much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess WWW store the request result as a bytes array internally, and convert it to a string when you access the `text` *field* (is this really a field then ?).

So, no matter what, converting that bytes to string will require to allocate memory and use the proper encoding to process that byte array.

Your best bet is to extract the data directly from the byte array, without converting it to a big string first.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can wrap the byte array in a `MemoryStream`, and wrap it again in a `StreamReader` with the appropriate encoding (OBJ files are plain ASCII I guess).

Your file is gonna be converted incrementally, as you read it.

Use that `yield` pattern in your processing loop, and it should be good !

Comment: I think this is a solution but, how i extract one line per time.

Comment: Use a StringReader, if it's available on the platform.

Comment: Is .Net Framework 3.5, but i need to read one line in one array of bytes. Not in one string.

Comment: @user3541917 search the array for the next byte that equals 13 (carriage return).

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
WWW file = new WWW(path);
while(!file.isDone)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
}
string text = file.text;
```

Comment: A slow process is `string text = file.text;`